# How to detect from a shellscript that a file on remote server has changed?

Tags: linux, bash

What could be used to detect that remote file is different compared to a local file?

Possibly using ssh as a channel for communication. Scripted in bash, having linux servers in mind.

This could be based on file content (md5sum), but I'd like to deduce (from modification time) which file is newer...

I'm trying to detect if some config files have been edited on the servers compared to copies under version control, and merge the changes.

Comment: If the remote file is in a directory with no subdirectories you could use `find RemoteDir -name RemoteName -newer LocalFilePath`; or you could use `ls --full-time` on both files and compare the date and time fields, which are in a format for direct comparison.

Comment: Did the answer below work/help?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that would handle both local and remote (over ssh) hosts would be `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -n -c src/ dst/
```

The `-n` flag tells `rsync` not to actually do any transfers - so the output would be just the files that it *wants* to transfer, or, the changed files. The `-c` ensures that rsync does an MD5 comparison. If you want to just do a match against size and last modification time, just omit `-c`.

---

Another method, would be to check both directories in to `git` repositories. This requires significant familiarity with `git` but could be accomplished by maintaining each host's files in a separate branch. Then one can `git fetch` (which omits the implied merge of `git pull`) and use `git diff` between branches to inspect changes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162800/git-diff-between-cloned-and-original-remote-repository) may be useful in such a setup.